# What is the difference between static and dynamic modules in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I wanted to know what is the difference between static and dynamic modules in nginx and which ones are better? What are the advantages/disadvantages of building a module as static / dynamic module.

Comment: In nginx, dynamic modules can be added on the fly, simply get the ".so" file, place it in the modules folder and include it in the conf folder. Restart and you are set to go. With static modules you have to convert them to dynamic which involves compiling them with the same version of nginx which u are running. Once you get the ".so" u are good to go again.